# Getting script to work when switching to different user

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh

I have some concerns regarding the script below which creates folder per line from file. Folder.list is located in /scripts/ . 1st script works smoothly but the 2nd script doesn't work when  trying to switch to different user.

-- 1st script--

```
#!/bin/ksh
while read line
do
if [ ! -d $line ]
    then
     mkdir -p $line >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Directory $line created."
     else
    echo "Error: $line directory exists!"
   fi
done < folder.list
```

--2nd script--

```
#!/bin/ksh
#Switch user
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/keys/askpass.sh
sudo -A su - appuser<<EOF

#Go to folder.list directory
cd /scripts/


while read line
do
if [ ! -d $line ]
    then
     mkdir -p $line >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Directory $line created."
    else
    echo "Error: $line directory exists!"
   fi
done < folder.list
EOF
```

Comment: at first sight, `$line` should be escaped to `\$line` ?

Comment: It works in 1st script without the escape characters but If im going to put escape characters it will create folder with just $line and will not read the line from a file.

Comment: Man, you need to use the shell's arguments for this stuff. Try naming a folder `;rm -rf /` and see what happens.

Comment: Why do you need a script just to do `xargs mkdir -vp <folder.list`?

Comment: Hi Toby, yes that works and thanks for that but I want to check if directory is existing and will throw a message if existing or not.

Answer (score 1):

To be more clear

consider

```
cat <<EOF

foo bar $baz

EOF

fubar="Hello World"

cat <<EOF

echo $fubar
print \$fubar

EOF
```

when run will give

```
foo bar


echo Hello World
print $fubar
```

on first cat  you'll notice that $baz variable disappear (provided it is not set).

on second run, I set fubar variable, it is echoed with it's value, to echo `$fubar` I escape `$`.

your second script should be

```
#!/bin/ksh
#Switch user
export SUDO_ASKPASS=/keys/askpass.sh
sudo -A su - appuser<<EOF

#Go to folder.list directory
cd /scripts/


while read line
do
if [ ! -d \$line ]
    then
     mkdir -p \$line >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Directory \$line created."
    else
    echo "Error: \$line directory exists!"
   fi
done < folder.list
EOF
```

Comment: Hi Archermar, thanks for your response but I tried this before to put escape characters.. the script wont read the line from a file instead, it will just create a folder where i execute the scripts, folder name is "$line"